# mysql error 1451

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1451

I have mysql error with code 1451.

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`online_store_admin`.`osa_admin_logs`, CONSTRAINT `fk_admins_logs` FOREIGN KEY (`aid`) REFERENCES `osa_admins` (`aid`))

here sql statement :

> ```
> drop table if exists osa_admins;
> create table if not exists osa_admins(
>  aid int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
>  uid varchar(50) not null, 
>  pass char(41) not null, 
>  erp_id int unsigned not null, 
>  last_login int unsigned not null,
>  is_block tinyint unsigned not null,
>  menus varchar(50) not null,
>  is_login tinyint unsigned not null,
>  ip_login char(15) not null,
>
>  constraint idx_osa_admins primary key using btree(aid)
> );
> insert into osa_admins value
> (NULL, 'root', password('6789'), '0', '0', '0', '*', '0', '127.000.000.001'),
> (NULL, 'ryu', password('6789'), '0', '0', '0', '*', '0', '127.000.000.001');
>
> drop table if exists osa_admin_logs;
> create table if not exists osa_admin_logs(
>  lid bigint unsigned not null,
>  aid int unsigned not null,
>  dates int unsigned not null,
>  logs text not null,
>
>  constraint idx_osa_admin_logs primary key using btree(lid),
>  constraint fk_admins_logs foreign key (aid)
>   references osa_admins(aid)
>   match full
>   on update cascade
>   on delete cascade
> );
> insert into osa_admin_logs values
> (NULL, '2', '0', 'some action here'),
> (NULL, '2', '0', 'again, some action here');
> ```

Problem come when i use this statement:

> delete from osa_admins where aid='2';

i think i had set "on delete cascade". anyone know how to delete cascade? so i don't necessary to manual detelet osa_admin_logs data. oh, i using innodb as db engine(default mysql that i have).

And sorry i ask same question that had answer, just let me know where i can get my question.

Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the `match full` from the constraint

> Use of an explicit MATCH clause will
> not have the specified effect, and
> also causes ON DELETE and ON UPDATE
> clauses to be ignored. For these
> reasons, specifying MATCH should be
> avoided.

MySql docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 13):

Use the following commands to do this:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0; 
DELETE FROM your_table_name WHERE your_condition;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: This is very dangerous; it just tells the computer to ignore the constraints.  The accepted answer is a better solution.  I think you will also find changing the `DELETE` part of the query to a `SELECT * FROM`, it may return valid results.

Comment: it can make sql file corrupt, because foreign_key is not found