# Error 1451 with "on update cascade" and "on delete cascade"

Tags: mysql

I created a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE progettoschemas.categories (
  id DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  fatherid DOUBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (fatherid) REFERENCES progettoschemas.categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

but when I do this query:

```
UPDATE categories SET id = 33 WHERE id = 1
```

I get: Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`categories`, CONSTRAINT `legame_padrefiglio` FOREIGN KEY (`fatherid`) REFERENCES `categorie` (`id`))

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Example of my db]

This is a representation of my database

Comment: ca we see all of your datas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql error 1451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505624/mysql-error-1451)

Comment: @bigtheo I don't think so, it looks slightly different. Btw I'm adding my datas to the post

Comment: Check the 2nd paragraph here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @forpas thank you. So basically I can't do on update cascade for my db?

Comment: I'm afraid so...